# Pass query result to method (Linq, Wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, linq, datacontext

I have method to save all values from table to txt file:

```
        UserDataDBsDataContext dataContext = new UserDataDBsDataContext();
        List<UserData> usersL = (from u in dataContext.UserDatas
                                 select u).ToList();

        var properties = typeof(UserData).GetProperties();
        var userValues = new List<string>();

        foreach (var user in usersL)
        {
            var values = new List<object>();
            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                object value = property.GetValue(user, null);
                values.Add(value);
            }
            userValues.Add(string.Join(",", values));
        }
        File.WriteAllLines("my_data.txt", userValues);
```

Now I have two query and I want to do exactly the same, so I tried to create separate method responsible for looping table values.

**Loop Method:**

```
    public void loopProp(PropertyInfo[] properites, List<string> addedValues)
    {           
        foreach (var qrl in ...........)
        {
            var values = new List<object>();
            foreach (var property in properites)
            {
                object value = property.GetValue(qrl, null);
                values.Add(value);
            }
            addedValues.Add(string.Join(",", values));
        }
        File.WriteAllLines("my_passed_data.txt", addedValues);
    }
```

**But** I don't know, how to pass query result(**ar** or **ud**):

**My code**:

```
List<AutoRef> ar = (from a in rjdc.AutoRefs
                    select a).ToList();
List<UserDataRef> ud = (from u in rjdc.UserDataRefs
                       select u).ToList();

            var propertiesAutoRef = typeof(AutoRef).GetProperties();
            var autoValues = new List<string>();

            var propertiesUserRef = typeof(UserDataRef).GetProperties();
            var userValues = new List<string>();

            //loopProp(propertiesAutoRef, autoValues);
            //loopProp(propertiesUserRef, userValues);
```

Comment: What problem do you have with `loopProp(propertiesAutoRef, autoValues);` for example?

Comment: this is fine, I dont know how to pass "ar" or "ud" :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering your concrete question. You should make the method generic and pass the source as `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public void loopProp<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, PropertyInfo[] properites, List<string> addedValues)
{           
    foreach (var qrl in source)
    {
        // ...
    }
    File.WriteAllLines("my_passed_data.txt", addedValues);
}
```

Usage:

```
loopProp(ar, propertiesAutoRef, autoValues);
loopProp(ud, propertiesUserRef, userValues);
```

Probably you should pass the file path argument as well instead of hardcoding it inside the method.

Comment: thanks Ivan.......what do you mean by file path? ("my_passed_data.txt")?

Comment: Yes. Because I assume you don't want the second call to overwrite the same file :)

Comment: probably it will be appened, but anyway thanks for the comment @Ivan

Comment: It will not (should use `File.AppendAllLines` instead), but anyway, it's irrelevant to the subject. Cheers.